# I have a Mouse Click Event handler which works when i select the first time but..?

Tags: winforms, ms-access, vba

I have a `DataGridView` in C# which is connected with my Access database. I see all the books on my `DataGridView`. I have created a mouse Click event handler to select a row than I can save that row, as you see below:

```
private void Mouse_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        temp = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index.ToSt… 

        //This one is selecting the row. To do that select panel>event> on MouseClick write name and double click:

        MessageBox.Show("You have selected the row " + temp);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

It works when I open the form. However, after I save the selected row to another database, the Mouse Click event handler stop working. In other words, after saving the first selected row, when I come back to select another row and save to database the Mouse Click Event handler does not work. The Message says row is out of range.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mouse Click Event handler does not work properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172639/mouse-click-event-handler-does-not-work-properly)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give too much information related to connection type, Event Handler and more importantly the way you save/update the record so I'm just guessing here: aren't you accidentally overwriting the DataSource of your grid? That's the only thing I can imagine for such behavior ("row is out of range" - which also assumes the event still works as intended but the code in the function cannot see the data anymore).

Comment: After selecting the row, I click on SaveButton to save the selected row to another database which works, but when I want to select different book from my dataGridView1, then the MouseClick event does not work. The below is the code for the SaveButton.

Comment: After selecting the row, I click on SaveButton to save the selected row to another database which works, but when I want to select different book from my dataGridView1, then the MouseClick event does not work. The below is the code for the SaveButton. i am trying to post the code, but it did not let me i post part of the code here:private void SaveButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
       { InitializeComponent();
mycode = new leDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Desktop\data.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

Comment: OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Copy(BookName, AuthorName, ISBN, Quantity, Price) Values ('" + bookNameVariable[Convert.ToInt16(temp)] + "', '" + authorName[Convert.ToUInt32(temp)] + "','" + ISBN[Convert.ToInt16(temp)] + "','" + Quantity[Convert.ToInt16(temp)] + "','" + Price[Convert.ToInt16(temp)] + "')";
command.Connection = mycode;
mycode.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();mycode.Close();

Comment: Try to refresh/requery your grid after all the code was executed in your SaveButton. Even better to add it as the last line of code in 'Mouse_Click' (for testing purposes). My only guess here is, as I wrote above that the grid's data/datasource got invalid.